# how to set value to AttemptedValue of ValueProvide + MVC 4

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am stuck into a strange problem.

I have a check box in my MVC view, that is being rendered from the jQuery.

```
<div>
    <label for="check" class="chk">
        Del ?
    <input id="IsSoftDeleted" name="IsSoftDeleted" data-val-required="The Del? field is required." data-val="true" type="checkbox" class="check"  />
    </label>
</div>
```

The script was written in such way that the values for checked and unchecked are coming as on and off.

I have handled it as below in my bodel binder:

```
protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        bool softDelete = Convert.ToBoolean(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("IsSoftDeleted").AttemptedValue != null
                  && bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("IsSoftDeleted").AttemptedValue == "on" ? "true" : "false");


        return OrgFactory.Create(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Caption").AttemptedValue,
            bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("NameInUse").AttemptedValue,
            bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Description").AttemptedValue,
            softDelete, new Party());
    }
```

This works fine, the organization's IsSoftDeleted property is now true or false.

However since the IsSoftDeleted in boolean in my Model class, the ModelState is referring to Attempted Value i.e., on and ModelState is becoming false.

I have tried to set value to AttemptedValue property but it is inaccessible.

Can somebody advise how can I fix it plsss?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Chill out!!!
We handled it currently in jQuery..

I guess we cannot extend the valueprovider class, if yes please give use too some ways how can we do that!!